# Smallest subgroup of unitary group, containing diagonal matrices and a fixed unitary matrix is the whole group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups, unitary-matrices

Suppose that $U_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the group of unitary matrices of dimension $n$ over complex numbers. Fix a unitary matrix $A \in U_n(\mathbb{C})$ and consider the smallest subgroup $K \subseteq U_n(\mathbb{C}) $, that contains all diagonal matrices (maximal torus group) and also $A$. It seems that apart from some exceptions for $A$ (like when $A$ is a diagonal matrix), $K = U_n(\mathbb{C}) $. Do you have any idea, if this is true, how to prove it and how to derive the exception cases?

Update: I'm interested in the case where $A$ is a [Circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix), i.e. it has the following form:
$$A=F^{-1}\cdot L\cdot F,$$
where $L$ is a diagonal matrix and $F$ is the [DFT matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix). I'm not sure if this restriction simplifies the problem or not.

Comment: Another exception is when $A$ is a permutation matrix.

Comment: In general, we should have $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}:~ A^k \neq I_n$.

Comment: Another exception is whenever $A$ is (non-trivially) **block-diagonal**. For instance, any rotation
$$
A = \pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0\\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1}
$$
in the case that $n = 3$.